# typescript anonymous getter and setter (kind of boxing and unboxing)

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter-setter

I need a Typescript(possibly JavaScript) object with anonymous setter and getter.
I would like something like:

```
class clsX{
    a : string,
    b : any,
    public get () : any { return someFuncG(); }
    public set (v: any) { someFuncS(v); } 
}
var x : clsX;
var y : any;
y = x; // y assigned with return of someFuncG.
x = y; // execute someFuncS( y )
```

This can be easily achieved in C# (using cast operator) but I wonder if it is possible in typescript. Kind of boxing and unboxing.

Comment: [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) might be an option

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the following in effect:

```
function dummyGet() {
    console.log('We are getting something');
    return 1;
}

function dummySet(value) {
    console.log('We are setting something');
    console.log('The new value is', value);
}

Object.defineProperty(
    window, // `global` in Node.js
    'x',
    {
        get() { return dummyGet(); },
        set(x) { dummySet(x); }
    }
);
```

But it seems hard to be related to the class syntax.